# Foreground without blocking functions

Tags: html, css, image, mouse

I have a normal website with some pictures in it. When I hover over the pictures with the mouse it plays a short audio. Now I want to insert a big black dot as a foreground picture. And this dot will cover some pictures. Now with this I still want to use the hover function even if the pictures are being covered.(It should still detect if the picture is being hovered by the mouse even though they are covered). This should be simulating (in a way) visual impairment.

it looks like this and the dots size will change if I navigate to another page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaPO2.jpg

1. How can I insert a (foreground) picture that covers the whole page?
2. How can I use the hover function even though the pictures are covered?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the foreground picture child of the element that is to be hovered:

```
#element:hover #foregroundpicture{
   display:fixed; 
   width:100%; 
   top:0; 
   left:0
}
```